# Mongoose, pull from subdocument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my document:

```
{ 
  password: '87654321',
  title: 'Organization A',
  members: 
   [ { tier: 1,
       joinedDate: Sun May 12 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST),
       user: 543fc462ed385e5e77a98d56 
     },
     { tier: 2,
       joinedDate: Sat May 11 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST),
       user: 543fc462ed385e5e77a98d57 
     },
     { tier: 3,
       joinedDate: Fri May 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST),
       user: 543fc462ed385e5e77a98d58 
     }
    ]
}
```

I want to write a query that pulls a member with a given user _.id

The pull command is probably what I should use

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray-pull

```
mongoose.model('organization').findOne({_id:user.organization}, function(err, org){
      org.members.pull({'user._id':user._id});
      org.save();
    })
```

It's not working. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

My schema:

```
var organizationSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  password: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
  members: [
    {
      tier: { type: Number, required: true, min:1, max:4},
      joinedDate: Date,
      user:{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user',
        required: true,
        unique:true
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: are you getting the data into org variable?

Comment: Yes, organization is returned

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears that the `MongooseArray#pull` method only works if your elements have `_id` properties.

I find it easier to use direct calls to `update` to avoid these sorts of surprises:

```
mongoose.model('organization').update(
    {_id: user.organization},
    {$pull: {members: {user: user._id}}},
    function(err, numAffected) { ... }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any id referenced in your members array, remove _id and do it directly to your user property since that's what is on the schema.

```
mongoose.model('organization').findOne({_id:user.organization}, function(err, org){
      org.members.pull({'user':user._id});
      org.save();
    })
```

**EDIT:** 
maybe this one

```
mongoose.model('organization').update({ _id: user.organization }, {$pull: 
{members.user: user._id}}, {}, function(err, numAffected){
 //check numAffected

});
```

try that out!

Comment: can you post your schema?

Comment: Very odd, I get 1 on numAffected but when I look in my database, it's still there. You probably have a right answer. Maybe my unit test that make something funny. I'll approve when I find whats wrong.

Comment: no worries! play around with the update clause, it's better since there's an atomic operation when you are using pull.

Comment: try to change your model definition for the user type to Schema.Types.ObjectId

Comment: Isn't that what I have? user :{ type: Schema.objectId, ref:'user'})?

Comment: Seems I get 1 on numAffected regardless what I put in user._id

Comment: I'm not so sure about Schema.objectId, I haven't looked at it in that way it may worth to try it out anyway, probably one reason could be the id not being in the right format as an example when you pass an id as a string you have to do an explicit cast to object id otherwise you're not going to find the value

Comment: your org query is fine , to me seems like it's not hitting the right element in the array, you may focus on that part

Comment: just following up here, did you find the issue?

Comment: No. Ended up with doing an ugly for-loop to find the member and then using org.members.id(memberId).remove(). Very annoying. I'll put a bounty on it tomorrow.