# Node JS Mongoose PULL query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I find many great answers here on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786075/mongoose-deleting-pull-a-document-within-an-array-does-not-work-with-objectid) answer an [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405798/mongoose-pull-from-subdocument). But i can not get it to work...
I tried `ObjectId("55cf816559d2fc8d0e6c14a8")` in the query where the id is.

This query works when robotmongo run it:

```
db.getCollection('events').update(
    { "_id": ObjectId("55cf816559d2fc8d0e6c14a8") }, 
    { "$pull": { "workers" : { "_id": ObjectId("55cf89ac7cba1d0a10ca86c7")}}},
    false,
    true
)
```

Side note, what is the false,true for?

Here is my current code

```
event.update(
    {'_id': "55cf816559d2fc8d0e6c14a8"}, 
    { "$pull": { "workers" : {_id: "55cf89ac7cba1d0a10ca86c7"}}},
    function(err, result) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
    }
);
```

I do not get any errors and the result is equal to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me. You must be doing something differently and incorrectly:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');


var workerSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

var eventSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  workers: [workerSchema]
});


var Event = mongoose.model( 'Event', eventSchema );

async.series(
  [
    function(callback) {
      Event.remove({},function(err) {
        callback(err);
      });
    },
    function(callback) {
      var event = new Event({
        _id: "55cf816559d2fc8d0e6c14a8",
        name: "Great thing"
      });
      event.workers.push({
        _id: "55cf89ac7cba1d0a10ca86c7",
        name: "Worker1"
      });
      event.save(function(err,event) {
        console.log(event);
        callback(err);
      });
    },
    function(callback) {
      Event.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "_id": "55cf816559d2fc8d0e6c14a8" },
        { "$pull": { "workers": { "_id": "55cf89ac7cba1d0a10ca86c7" } } },
        { "new": true },
        function(err,event) {
          console.log(event)
          callback(err);
        }
      );
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

With the expected output:

```
{ __v: 0,
  _id: 55cf816559d2fc8d0e6c14a8,
  name: 'Great thing',
  workers: [ { _id: 55cf89ac7cba1d0a10ca86c7, name: 'Worker1' } ] }
{ _id: 55cf816559d2fc8d0e6c14a8,
  name: 'Great thing',
  __v: 0,
  workers: [] }
```

Comment: Thanks, what was wrong with my code? Another question "{ "new": true },"  What is that for?

Comment: @KristerJohansson The `.findOneAndUpdate()` and similar methods will all modify the matched document and return the document. The `{ "new": true }` modifies the default behavior which is to return the "original" document before modification to return instead the "modified" document. It isn't needed, but it's just a way of showing the result here. Not sure what was really wrong with your code, but this gives you something working to compare with. Mongoose will cast the implied "_id" fields as an ObjectId automatically.