# remove item from nested array using $pull

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hey I have one problem with remove nested array from my database, I would like use `findOneAndUpdate` and `$pull`. My point is to remove item from `reply` array. I try find comments item by `_id` and remove this reply item, but this not working. Please look on my code below.

my schema

```
var productSchema = new Schema({

description: [{
    type: String,
    require: true,
}],
comments: [{
    body: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
    },
    reply: [{
        body: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
        },
        author: {
            type: String,
        }, date: {
            type: Date,
        }
    }]
  }]
});
```

api

```
router.put('/dashboard/admin/komentarz/odpowiedz/usun/', function(req, res) {  
var currentCourse = req.body._id; // main item id
var deleteReply = req.body.reply; // reply item id
var commentId = req.body.commentId // comments item id
Product.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: currentCourse }, { $pull: { reply: req.body.reply }}, function(err, product){
   //some code
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take ref from [Mongoose, pull from subdocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405798/mongoose-pull-from-subdocument)

```
Product.findOneAndUpdate({ 
    _id: currentCourse,
    // make sure sub document have a unique field let take _id
    "comments._id" : 'commentId' 
}, 
{ 
    $pull:  { 
        "comments.$.reply": {
            _id:'replyId'
        } 
    }
},
{
    upsert:false,
    new:true
}, function(err, product){
   //some code
})
```